# Mix nested and referenced elements in XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Often, data structures are not strictly hierarchical. For instance, consider a team consisting of players, and marking one of those players as captain:

[image]

If I would serialize an instance of this model to XML, I would expect some structure like:

```
<Team id="team1">
    <Players>
        <Player id="player1"/>
        <Player id="player2"/>
        <Player id="player3"/>
        <Player id="player4"/>
    </Players>
    <Captain ref="player3"/>
</Team>
```

That is, the aggregation is serialized as nested elements and the directed association is serialized with the reference to an id.

---

I would like to achieve this from C# code without having to write custom XML serializers, preferably just by adding an attribute, something like:

```
class Team
{
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }

    [XmlReference]
    public Player Captain { get; set; }
}
```

Does anything like this exist? I had a look at XML schema's but it doesn't seem to provide what I need here.

---

**Bonus**: It would be even better if I could *generate* the intermediate C# code, with the appropriate attributes set, directly from the UML - or any other modeling formalism for that matter. In the end, I just want to be able to specify the type of association on a high abstraction level and have the XML serialization conform to that, with the least amount of effort / room for mistakes.

Comment: You may introduce a captain-class with a property ref that you serialize as attribute instead of an element (doing so will require the XmlAttribute-attribute)

Comment: Do you mind what the XML actually looks like?  `DataContractSerializer` offers this with the `IsReference` property (and generally has better performance).

Answer (score 1):

As I alluded in the comments, if you're not fussy about the actual XML itself then `DataContractSerializer` can handle these sort of reference semantics.

You add attributes like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Team
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Player Captain { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Player
{

}
```

And a team such as this one:

```
var p1 = new Player();
var p2 = new Player();
var p3 = new Player();

var team = new Team
{
    Players = new List<Player>
    {
        p1,
        p2,
        p3
    },
    Captain = p3
};
```

Would be serialized to XML like this:

```
<Team xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication1">
    <Captain z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
    <Players>
        <Player z:Id="i2" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
        <Player z:Id="i3" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
        <Player z:Ref="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
    </Players>
</Team>
```

On deserialization, the same object would appear as `Captain` and as the third player in the `Players` list.

If you want more control then you're likely going to have to implement this all yourself.

Comment: This would almost suit my needs, except that I really don't want the serializer to decide where to inline the object and where to reference, but I guess I cannot override the default behavior? (Other than tweaking the model to make sure that the inline-objects are offered to the serializer first, which is a big no-go of course.)

Comment: It was built for shifting data around, there's very little control over how it does that (unlike `XmlSerializer`).  You can specify `Order` on the `DataMember` attributes to serialize `Players` first - by virtue of that, the player with  'z:Ref' will be the `Captain`.

Comment: I assume you're using this output somewhere else rather than just reading it back into the serializer again?

Comment: Yes, our datamodel is serialized for diagnostic purposes amongst others, and our domain experts manually inspect xml files consisting of up to 50k lines (it's arguable whether that's smart, but they can do that). We currently have a heavy custom way to serialize our data model properly, but since were gonna change big parts of our model anyway, I was hoping for an off-the-shelf solution to replace that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the captain-class as follows:

```
class Captain {
    [XmlAttribute("ref")]
    public string reference {get;set;}
}
```

Now your Team has this:

```
class Team
{
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }

    public Captain Captain { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this would work for serialization but I find it rather invasive from a code point-of-view. I cannot use `someTeam.Captain`  anymore to obtain the captain object, which is undesirable.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele This is of course true, you could include the actual player as property within your captain-class and call `team.Captain.Player`, however this won´t work on an automatic approach.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't know of anything like you want in XML. I am no expert though and only use XML for serialisation/deserialisation. I might have a viable solution for you though.
You can find a lot of information on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/943242d1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you have a schema file you can use [XSD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s2x1sy7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create classes.
I usually go the other way round and create the classes first then create a schema for it to validate the data I receive.

I would either use a property on Players to tell who is the Captain and thus have the Property on Team only return Player having IsCaptain == true

```
class Team
{
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public Player Captain { get { return Players.Find(p => p.IsCaptain); } }
}
class Player
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsCaptain { get; set; }
}
```

or simply store the id in CaptainID on Team for serialisation and deserialisation and have property Player Captain ignored in xml serialisation.

```
class Team
{
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public string CaptainID { get; set; }

    [NonSerialized]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public Player Captain { get { return Players.Find(p => p.ID == CaptainID); } }
}
```